# auto select the second option in a select when no of options is greater than 1

Tags: jquery

I have multiple select option with a common class name. I want to select the second option  of each select if the option are greater than 1.

for eg.

```
<select  class="drop">
   <option name="option" value="Option 1"></option>
</select>

<select  class="drop">
   <option name="option" value="Option 1"></option>
   <option name="option" value="Option 2"></option>
   <option name="option" value="Option 3"></option>
</select>

<select  class="drop">
   <option name="option" value="Option 1"></option>
   <option name="option" value="Option 2"></option>
   <option name="option" value="Option 3"></option>
</select>
```

For the 2 and 3 select option 2 should be auto selected.

```
$('.drop').each(function(i, obj) {

});
```

How do i check the no of options in each select and accordingly select the second option if the no of options is greater than 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to do like this:

```
$('.drop').each(function (i, obj) {

    if ($(this).find("option").length > 1) { // check if curent dropdown options greater than 1
        $(this).find("option").eq(1).prop("selected", true); // set 2nd option selected
    }

});
```

### FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/5de0227h/